# Kotlin: redundant if statement

Tags: if-statement, kotlin

I have this code:

```
val leftEnoughRoom = if(fx1 > eachSideBesidesFace){
    true
}else{
    false
}
```

And get the warning:

```
This inspection reports if statements which can be simplified to single statements. For example:  
if (foo()) {
   return true
} else {
   return false
}
can be simplified to return foo().
```

What does it want me to do? When I do:

```
if(fx1 > eachSideBesidesFace){
    val leftEnoughRoom = true
}else{
    val leftEnoughRoom = false
}
```

Then `leftEnoughRoom` is not reachable below any more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
fx1 > eachSideBesidesFace
```

is a boolean statement. You don't need the if-else:

```
val leftEnoughRoom = fx1 > eachSideBesidesFace
```

As a sidenote, you can click the underlined expression, hit Alt+Enter and then have Android Studio automatically optimize the code.

Comment: There was no mention of Android Studio in the question, but it works in IntelliJ too, assuming the keybindings are set to the defaults. Otherwise, it might require different keys

Comment: @Zoe IntelliJ with the Android plugin and Android Studio are functionally equivalent. IntelliJ just doesn't play nice with Gradle.

Comment: I use IntelliJ for Android, and it works fine. I just pointed it out because there's no guarantee OP actually uses Android Studio. It is either way a JetBrains IDE, yes, but it doesn't *have* to be Android Studio